# User-customizable rails authorization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authorization

Seems there is an abundance of popular declarative-style authorization plugins, which allow you to somehow state in the code that, e.g., this controller action can be accessed by users with such-and-such roles.

But what if I need a more dynamic scheme. I want to have an admin area, with a list of all authorizable actions and an ability to assign permissions on actions from the UI.

I have ideas how to implement it from scratch, like to define a model corresponding to a controller and/or action and store the permissions via normal associations.  Just wonder if there are any ready solutions to this.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Take a peek at the [Authlogic Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/160-authlogic), it will get you started in the right direction. Here's the link to the [Authlogic project on GitHub](http://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic/tree/master).